# Extending a child object with Knockout Mapping

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Consider this JSON object:

```
{
    "BusinessModels":[
        { 
            "Id":1,
            "Name":"Business to Business",
            "Businesses":[],
            "ReportTypes":[
                {...},
                {...},
                {
                    "Id":6,
                    "Name":"Risk",
                    "BusinessModelId":1,
                    "Reports":[
                        {
                            "Id": 4,
                            "Name": "Test",
                            "Value": ko.observable() // NEED TO ADD THIS PROPERTY USING MAPPING
                        },
                        {...}
                    ]
                }
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to add the value using the following code, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
var mapping = {
    'BusinessModels': {
        create: function(options) {
            return new function() {
                var self = options.data;
                self.SelectedBusiness = ko.observable();
                self.Businesses.unshift({ Id: 0, Name: 'All Clients' });
                ko.mapping.fromJS(self, {}, this);
            };
        }
    },
    'Reports': {
        create: function (options) {
            return new function () {
                var self = options.data;
                self.Value = ko.observable();
                ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, {}, this);
            };
        }
     }
};

var model = ko.mapping.fromJSON(raw, mapping);
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

I need to give a child object "Reports" a `ko.observable` object named `Value`. How do I go about doing this in ko.mapping?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking.  Can you post an "after" object if you were to construct it manually with the structure you want.

Comment: I updated my comment. I just need to add a property to a child and my mapping is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that was quick. I figured out the answer.

```
var mapping = {
    'BusinessModels': {
        create: function (options) {
            return new function () {
                var self = options.data;
                self.SelectedBusiness = ko.observable();
                self.Businesses.unshift({ Id: 0, Name: 'All Clients' });
                ko.mapping.fromJS(self, mapping, this);
            };
        }
    },
    'Reports': {
        create: function (options) {
            return new function () {
                var self = options.data;
                self.Value = ko.observable();
                ko.mapping.fromJS(self, mapping, this);
            };
        }
    }
};
```

Rather than using `ko.mapping.fromJS(self, {}, this)` I used `ko.mapping.fromJS(self, mapping, this)`. The reason is because Reports is a nested object of BusinessModels.

Comment: I was about to post virtually the same thing.  ko.mapping.fromJS starts a brand new map and unless you supply a mapping configuration it will just do a default map.  The fact that Reports is a child of BusinessModels is irrelevant.  I would supply an explicit map to the fromJS function containing only the Reports definition, not pass in the outer mapping, and the again into the Reports fromJS call, you might get into a infinite loop if the JSON field names are repeated